# Laravel 3 for each through a returned array using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, foreach, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I am using Laravel 3, I think it's awesome.
OK, I set my DB config to return assoc arrays to help me out.
My controller works fine, the problem I am having is:
How do I pass the multiple arrays returned to a blade template for cycling thru a for each?

eg:

```
 Route::get('allprop', function() {

    $data= User::find(165)->property;

});
```

This returns:

```
 array(45) {
  [0]=>
  object(Property)#42 (5) {
    ["attributes"]=>
   array(52) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(71)
  ["code"]=>
  string(32) "b073d07a1357bebf0a6c8b0a193a561b"
  ["ownerid"]=>
  int(165)
  ["profileid"]=>
  int(23)
  ["unit_num"]=>
  string(3) "101"
  ["street_num"]=>
  string(3) "498"
  ["address1"]=>
  string(10) "Mifarm Rd."
  ["address2"]=>
  string(8) "Address2"
  ["city"]=>
  string(11) "White Stone"
  ["county"]=>
  string(4) "York"
  ["subdivision"]=>
  string(11) "White Stone"
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "VA"
  ["postcode"]=>
```

When I pass the $data array to the template, I get lost on how to access each property of the array

it says variable $data not found when I try to :

```
 foreach ($data as $thumb){
  echo $thumb->postcode;
  }
```

Any help would be great, I know it is probably simple, but I can't seem to find an answer in the Docs or on Code Happy...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access `$data` in your template, you need to pass it to your template like this:

```
return View::make("yourtemplate")
    ->with("data", $data)
```

Comment: That was it, I was not defining the variable, I thought you could just pass the variable by itself. Thank you. BTW is there a more efficient method to get individual fields for each record?

Comment: Glad I could help. One way of getting only certain columns is by passing an array of the columns you want to the `get()` method: `User::query()->where_id(119)->get(array('username'));`

Answer (score 0):

The docs are pretty clear on this:

http://laravel.com/docs/views#binding-data-to-views